# looping through a jtable and passing its row values to an sql statement

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I have a table in my database which I displayed in my GUI program using a `JTable`. The `JTable` contains `driver`, `database URL`, `username`, `password`, `table name`, and `field name` / `Fields columns` respectively. I want to loop through this `JTable` rows, get their values and pass it this sql statements.

E.g: if the first row have

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBname, root, pass, TableName, FieldName
```

as the values of each field
And the second row have the following as the values of each field.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBname3, root, pass3, TableName3, FieldName3
```

---

```
for(iterate through the jtable and pass each row values to the sql statement)
{ 
    try
     {
      Class.forName(getDriver rows here);
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(getDatabase url here, getUsername, getPassword);
      Statement st = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from getTableName where field = getFieldName");
      while(rs.next())
     {
     System.out.println(rs.getString());
     }
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
     }
}
```

Is this possible and what do I need to do it?

Comment: Don't interact with the JTable, interact with its model instead

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Comment: okay, correction taken. Still is the pseudocode  feasible?

Comment: still waiting for an answer dudes